# Change Wireless Connection on a Schedule

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-task-scheduler

How can I change my wireless network connection to another connection on a schedule in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the wireless connection saved, you can use the `netsh wlan connect` command and the Task Scheduler.

Click the **Start** button and type *Task Scheduler*, then press Enter or select the **Task Scheduler** from the list.

Click the **Task Scheduler Library** in the left sidebar and click **Create Task** in the right sidebar.

Set your triggers to the schedule you want. In the **Actions** tab, click **New**.

In the New Action dialog, use the options below:

- **Action:** *Start a program*
- **Program/script:** `netsh`
- **Add arguments (optional):** `WLAN CONNECT "Network"` where "Network" is the name of your network.

Note that the name of your network must match **exactly**, including capitalization. Ex: "wifi" is not the same as "WiFi". The quotation marks are only necessary if your network name has spaces in it.

[image: Add Action dialog]